# Where is the signal handler located?

Tags: linux, kernel

I know that the signal handler should usually run in userland. But I don't understand where is the handler code located. Is it inside the binaries?

Comment: Each process may set up its own signal handler. Of course, the code to do this is "in the binary".

Comment: Have you googled some C examples on how to set up a signal handler?

Comment: Each signal handler (a process can have several) is registered with the kernel via a system call, so the kernel knows the address to enter the process at, to deliver that signal.